# Drawing lines between pairs in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have a tuple of pairs:

```
pairs=[(3,6),(7,2),(8,5),(9,5),(5,13),(10,6),(6,1),(1,13),(11,2),(2,13),(12,4),(4,13)]
```

Each pair describes a connection between two points, i.e there's a line between point 3 and point 6.

Currently, doing this:

```
i=0
for point in pairs:
    i+=1
    plt.plot(point,(i,i))
plt.show()
```

is giving me straight lines between each point and its respective destination:

[image]

However, I'm looking for connecting these lines together to create a graph of "bridges", something along the lines of:

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Where did you get `(3,3)` and `(6,6)` from? They're not in your original list...

Comment: @Eric: the first point is (3,6), he's doubling stuff up...

Comment: @Sheena: I'm suspicious that that's a typo, since plotting coordinates where `x == y` in all cases makes no sense.

Comment: @Erik. I know but that's what he asked for... I went through that in my answer. I suspected he wanted to draw lines between pairs of points eg from (3,6) to (7,2) so I detailed a solution to that also... I am told that was not the intension either so I'm a bit stumped about what is wanted. I'm waiting for the question to get updated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov),

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
edges = [
    (3,6),(7,2),(8,5),(9,5),(5,13),(10,6),(6,1),(1,13),(11,2),(2,13),(12,4),(4,13)]

G.add_edges_from(edges)
nx.draw(G)
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]